# Sharing the same model between Get and Post conroller methods

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I develop a Change Password form which controller has simply two methods:

```
public ActionResult ChangePassword(string email, Guid code)
{
    var model = new PasswordChangeModel { Email = email, ConfirmationCode = code };
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ChangePassword(PasswordChangeModel model)
{
    // use model class
}
```

Here GET method is invoked by direct link from confirmation e-mail. The POST method in invoked when submit button is clicked. The problem is that the model instance isn't shared between these two methods - the POST method is always has empy Guid ConfirmationCode property.

How can I force ASP.NET to use the same instance of model class? Or more generally, what is the best way to do the following: user clicks the link in his confirmation e-mail, then it is redirected to Change Password form, and after he clicks submit button, it is fired some action (save new password to DB, etc.)

Comment: If the `ConfirmationCode` is `null` when you post back then there is a problem with your model or the view. You need to post the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you have this property - "Guid code" in your PasswordChangeModel. And on your view you can have a hidden field to keep the Guid string like this below-

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.Code)
```

After you will post the model to the controller it will have the Guid string in the "Code" property of the model.